# Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I'm interested in algorithms to compute matrix multiplications. Is the Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm similar to the Strassen algorithm ?

I have two other questions:

1) Are the multiplications done at the end of the recursion, like the Strassen one ?

2) The $O(n^{2.38})$ refers to the number of multiplications or to any basic operations (additions...) ?

Thank you

Comment: Coppersmith & Winograd (1987), "[Matrix multiplication via arithmetic progressions](http://tbach.web.cern.ch/tbach/thesis/literature/matrix_cm.pdf)"